# How to fill blank cells with increment value in different cells in Excel?

Tags: excel

I have a column like the following:

```
     A | B | C
1| 1001|   | What formula?
2| 1002|No |
3| 1003|   |
4| 1004|No |
5| 1005|   |
6| 1006|   |
7| 1007|No |
```

I want to have something like this:

```
    A  | B | C
1| 1001|   | 1001
2| 1002|No |
3| 1003|   | 1002
4| 1004|No |
5| 1005|   | 1003
6| 1006|   | 1004
7| 1007|No |
8| 1008|   | 1005
```

So, basically the value in C, is the increment of last C value. I don't have any problem when how to indicate a cell is blank or not using IF, but for the increment value, i have some trouble.
So far i do have this formula for column C, but it's not working.

```
=IF(A2="", CELL("contents",C1)+1, IF(B2="","",MID(B2,1,4)+1))
```

What should i fix in the formula?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In case you can use a helper column, the following should solve your problem:

```
1001        1001    1001
1002        1002    1002
1003    No  1002    
1004    No  1002    
1005    No  1002    
1006        1003    1003
1007    No  1003    
1008        1004    1004
1009        1005    1005
1010        1006    1006
1011    No  1006    
1012        1007    1007
1013        1008    1008
1014        1009    1009
1015    No  1009    
1016        1010    1010
```

The cells C1 and D1 are simply =A1. The formula from C2 downwards is

```
=C1+1-(B2<>"")
```

In D2 you can use the formula

```
=IF(C2=C1,"",C2)
```

and copy it down.

If you want to solve the problem without the additional helper column, you can use this formula from C2 downwards:

```
{=IF(VLOOKUP(2^1000,$C$1:C1,1,TRUE)=A2-SUM(--($B$1:B2<>"")),"",A2-SUM(--($B$1:B2<>"")))}
```

C1 is again simply equal to A1.

Comment: Hi @LMM9790 Thanks for the help, and it WORKS! I use the "helper column" method, because the formula is easier for me to understand. But the Vlookup method also interesting, will get to understand that too.

Again, Thanks!

Comment: Hey @Erick Nyoto, I am glad it worked for you. The idea behind the Vlookup is as follows: the formula searches for 2^1000, which it obviously does not find, because it's the search matrix only contains smaller numbers. Therefore the formula returns the last non-empty cell. Regarding the search matrix, we need to make sure that the formula actually finds the last non-empty cell independently of the number of empty cells. Thats why the formula uses an expanding search matrix as you copy the formula down.

Answer (score 1):

This should work without the need for a helper column. Enter for all cells in Column C:

`=IF(ISBLANK(B2),IFERROR(INDIRECT("A"&MATCH(MAX($C$1:C1),$A$1:A2,0)+1),A2),"")`

It basically searches for the highest number currently in column C, finds the location of this in column A and then goes to the row below to take the next highest value.

Comment: Hi @Jordan Biddlecombe Thanks a lot for the help. But, unfortunately the formula seems didn't work. And some of the syntax is new for me (INDIRECT, MATCH). Thats a new learn for me. Again thanks for the help!